# Get total number of records on that day in a table in an array in last 30 days

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, query-optimization

I want to plot a graph to see the user growth in last 30 days.

So it will an array something like this: (an incremental array)

```
 [0,100,250,500,1000,1100.....5000,5500]
```

**Solution 1:** A stupid way to do this is to fire query for every day:

```
  (30.days.ago.to_date..Date.today).map {|date| User.where("Date(created_at) <= ?" , date).count}
```

But this will fire 30 queries.

**Solution 2:** Find all records using group by option and then loop over it and sumup previous records.

```
 User.group('Date(created_at)').count
 (30.days.ago.to_date..Date.today).map {|date| counts[date] || 0} //and again loop over it
 //and now start summing up previous ones elements to get an another array..
```

But both the solutions are useless. Any suggestions to make this as optimised ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do the following :

```
growth = []
users =  User.group('Date(created_at)').count

(30.days.ago.to_date..Date.today).each do |day|
  growth.push(growth.sum + (users[day] || 0))
end
```

Not tested but you get the idea.

Comment: I was thinking the same and specified in the question itself. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with sql itself,

Ex: I have the following table

```
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id | training_start_date |
+---------+---------------------+
|   15981 | 2012-10-08 06:12:45 |
|   15981 | 2012-10-08 06:13:26 |
|   15981 | 2012-10-08 06:29:34 |
|   15981 | 2012-10-08 06:33:53 |
| 1005933 | 2012-10-08 07:41:54 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

when I want to get how many users got the training each day, I could do

```
select count(user_id), training_start_date from training_users group by DATE_FORMAT(training_start_date, "%M %e, %Y");
```

This is the link which [helped me](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/04/group-by-having-sum-avg-and-count.html)

HTH